# JavaScript: Writing & appending text files from After Effects

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

Checking to see if a txt file already exists. If it exists I want to open and append. If !exist I want to create, open, write. I don't know how to append the file...

Here's my code so far:

```
function writeReport(path, reportText) {

    var reportFile = new File(path  + "/font_report.txt");

    if(reportFile.exists){
        alert('file already exists');

        reportFile.open("w");
        reportFile.write(reportText);
        reportFile.close();
    }
    else{

        var RCF_file = new File(reportFile);
        RCF_file.open("w");
        RCF_file.write(reportText);
        RCF_file.close();

    }
    alert('Report Complete');
}
```

The code in the if(exists) is obviously the same as in the else{} - not sure what it should be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append the file it needs to pass the append mode...

```
reportFile.open("a");
```